# Split a XML-file after group and sort by itemnumber with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, split, grouping

I'm currently trying to split a XML file which contains a number of objects with defined itemnumbers.

The XML-file looks roughly like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Orders>
<ShopOrder>
  <OrderHead>
    <OrderNo>F10068</OrderNo>
    <OrderDate>20181003</OrderDate>
    <CustomerNo>200078</CustomerNo>
  </OrderHead>
  <Order>
    <ItemNo>F10029</ItemNo>
  </Order>
</ShopOrder>
<ShopOrder>
  <OrderHead>
    <OrderNo>F10069</OrderNo>
    <OrderDate>20181004</OrderDate>
    <CustomerNo>200078</CustomerNo>
  </OrderHead>
  <Order>
    <ItemNo>F10078</ItemNo>
  </Order>
</ShopOrder>
<ShopOrder>
  <OrderHead>
    <OrderNo>F10070</OrderNo>
    <OrderDate>20181004</OrderDate>
    <CustomerNo>200089</CustomerNo>
  </OrderHead>
  <Order>
    <ItemNo>F10029</ItemNo>
  </Order>
</ShopOrder>
</Orders>

...
```

I now want to split the XML-file in several XML-files grouped by the ItemNo for further Analysis. The new XML-files should for example countain every **ShopOrder-Object** with the **ItemNo F10029**.

Further i want to name the new XML-file  named after ItemNo it contains.

Right now I can split the XML file in several XML-files but it only contains 1 ShopOrder per XML. I can't figure out how to combine the splitting with grouping the objects.

Can someone recommend a method that combines splitting with grouping after a certain criterium?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Update:
This is my current code

````
$dir = "C:\Users\User1\ShopOrder"
$in_file = "ShopOrder1234.xml"

)

$in_path = Join-Path -Path $dir -ChildPath $in_file

$out_file_base = "$($in_file.split(".")[0])_"

$xml_dec_regex = "<\?xml .*"
$blank_regex = "^\s*$"

$file_num = 1
$out_path = "$dir\$out_file_base$("{0:d6}" -f $file_num).xml"

$sr = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $in_path

$length = $sr.BaseStream.Length

Write-Progress -Activity "Splitting File" `
               -Status "File: $file_num" `
               -PercentComplete ($sr.BaseStream.Position / $length * 100)

$sw = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList $out_path

$line = $sr.ReadLine()

While ($line -match $blank_regex -and !$sr.EndOfStream) {

    $line = $sr.ReadLine()

}

$sw.WriteLine($line)

While (!$sr.EndOfStream) {

    $line = $sr.ReadLine()

    While ($line -match $blank_regex) {

        $line = $sr.ReadLine()

    }

    If ($line -match $xml_dec_regex) {
        
        $sw.close()
        $file_num += 1
        $out_path = "$dir\$out_file_base$("{0:d6}" -f $file_num).xml"
        $sw = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList $out_path
        Write-Progress -Activity "Splitting File" `
               -Status "File: $file_num" `
               -PercentComplete ($sr.BaseStream.Position / $length * 100)

    }

    $sw.WriteLine($line)

} 

$sr.close()
$sw.close()```
````

Comment: Please update your question to include your current code and it'll be easier for people to help you.

Comment: Your xml is invalid. No root tag and no closing `</ItemNo>` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like below, but first you need to make sure you have a valid XML:

Here, I have added a root node `<Orders>` and corrected the closing tags `</ItemNo>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Orders>
    <ShopOrder>
      <OrderHead>
        <OrderNo>F10068</OrderNo>
        <OrderDate>20181003</OrderDate>
        <CustomerNo>200078</CustomerNo>
      </OrderHead>
      <Order>
        <ItemNo>F10029</ItemNo>
      </Order>
    </ShopOrder>
    <ShopOrder>
      <OrderHead>
        <OrderNo>F10069</OrderNo>
        <OrderDate>20181004</OrderDate>
        <CustomerNo>200078</CustomerNo>
      </OrderHead>
      <Order>
        <ItemNo>F10078</ItemNo>
      </Order>
    </ShopOrder>
    <ShopOrder>
      <OrderHead>
        <OrderNo>F10070</OrderNo>
        <OrderDate>20181004</OrderDate>
        <CustomerNo>200089</CustomerNo>
      </OrderHead>
      <Order>
        <ItemNo>F10029</ItemNo>
      </Order>
    </ShopOrder>
</Orders>
```

The code

```powershell
$pathIn = 'C:\Users\User1\ShopOrder\ShopOrder1234.xml'
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $pathIn -Raw -Encoding UTF8

# get the root elements name
$rootElement = $xml.DocumentElement.LocalName

# create a template Here-String to be used for each new file
$xmlTemplate = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<$rootElement>{0}</$rootElement>
"@

$xml.$rootElement.ShopOrder | Group-Object -Property @{Expression = {$_.Order.ItemNo}} | ForEach-Object {
    # string the OuterXml text from all grouped ShopOrder nodes together
    $subXmlText = $xmlTemplate -f (($_.Group | ForEach-Object { $_.OuterXml }) -join [environment]::NewLine)
    # create a new XML document and load the xml text
    $doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
    $doc.LoadXml($subXmlText)
    # create a StringWriter and a XmlTextWriter to format the xml propertly
    $stringWriter = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter
    $xmlWriter    = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter($stringWriter)
    $xmlWriter.Formatting = [System.Xml.Formatting]::Indented
    $doc.WriteContentTo($xmlWriter)
    # write the new XML (as text file) to disk with filename taken from the groups Name (==> whatever was in <ItemNo>)
    $fileOut = Join-Path -Path ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($pathIn)) -ChildPath ('{0}.xml' -f $_.Name)
    Set-Content -Path $fileOut -Value $stringWriter.ToString() -Encoding UTF8
    # clean up the used objects
    $xmlWriter.Dispose()
    $stringWriter.Dispose()
    $doc = $null
}
```

---

As I understand it, your API returns mutilated XML..
Always best is to find out if that cannot be changed, so it delivers well-formed XML, but if you have no other option then to deal with what you get, You can try this:

```powershell
$pathIn    = 'C:\Users\User1\ShopOrder\ShopOrder1234.xml'
$apiReturn = Get-Content -Path $pathIn -Raw -Encoding UTF8

# the above gives you crappy text like
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <ShopOrder><OrderHead><OrderNo>F10068</OrderNo><OrderDate>20181003</OrderDate><CustomerNo>200078</CustomerNo> </OrderHead><Order><ItemNo>F10029</ItemNo></Order></ShopOrder><ShopOrder> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ShopOrder><OrderHead><OrderNo>F10069</OrderNo><OrderDate>20181004</OrderDate> <CustomerNo>200078</CustomerNo></OrderHead><Order><ItemNo>F10078</ItemNo></Order></ShopOrder>

# First create a template Here-String to be used for each new input AND output file
$xmlTemplate = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Orders>{0}</Orders>
"@

# split the text on the xml declaration line(s) and recombine the xmlnodes into one string
$subNodes = (($apiReturn -split '<\?xml[^>]+>').Trim() -ne '') -join ''
# use the template to form a single complete XML from this:
# remove doubled <ShopOrder> opening tags and fit it into the template
[xml]$xml = $xmlTemplate -f ($subNodes -replace '(<ShopOrder>){2,}', '$1')  

# the next code is really the (almost) unchanged code from my first answer

$xml.Orders.ShopOrder | Group-Object -Property @{Expression = {$_.Order.ItemNo}} | ForEach-Object {
    # string the OuterXml text from all grouped ShopOrder nodes together
    $subXmlText = $xmlTemplate -f (($_.Group | ForEach-Object { $_.OuterXml }) -join [environment]::NewLine)
    # create a new XML document and load the xml text
    $doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
    $doc.LoadXml($subXmlText)
    # create a StringWriter and a XmlTextWriter to format the xml propertly
    $stringWriter = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter
    $xmlWriter    = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter($stringWriter)
    $xmlWriter.Formatting = [System.Xml.Formatting]::Indented
    $doc.WriteContentTo($xmlWriter)

    # write the new XML (as text file) to disk with filename taken from the groups Name (==> whatever was in <ItemNo>)
    $fileOut = Join-Path -Path ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($pathIn)) -ChildPath ('{0}.xml' -f $_.Name)
    Set-Content -Path $fileOut -Value $stringWriter.ToString() -Encoding UTF8
    # clean up the used objects
    $xmlWriter.Dispose()
    $stringWriter.Dispose()
    $doc = $null
}
```

Comment: Hi Theo, this works superb! Thank you. The only issue I got is the error in line 3:  Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node." I'm pretty sure this is caused by the format my API is delivering me the XML that I want to work with. The file combines multiple XML-files with multiple root elements and multiple XML-declarations in the file. Is there any workaround to fix this issue in powershell ? Nevertheless thank you very much! 1/2

Comment: Just to clarify how the actual XML differs to the Test-XML I showed in the thread: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ShopOrder><OrderHead><OrderNo>F10068</OrderNo><OrderDate>20181003</OrderDate><CostumerNo>200078</CostumerNo>
</OrderHead><Order><ItemNo>F10029</ItemNo></Order></ShopOrder><ShopOrder>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ShopOrder><OrderHead><OrderNo>F10069</OrderNo><OrderDate>20181004</OrderDate>
<CostumerNo>200078</CostumerNo></OrderHead><Order><ItemNo>F10078</ItemNo></Order></ShopOrder> .....  2/2

Comment: @Domekie If that is **really** what your API delivers, I think it is high time not to use that anymore or if you have influence repair it. This certainly is higly mutilated xml-lookalike text..

Comment: Works great! I will definitely rearrange the sloppy API outcome. Thank you very much!